# How to Retrieve the subfields stored in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

The below data is stored in MongoDB. I am using Spring-Data and storing the data into mongoDB.
If I want to retrieve the fields ("id" or "Name") I can able to do, but if I want to retrieve the sub fields ("firstName" or "lastName")I can't.

(eg.)If I want to retrieve sub field "lastName" from the below data I can't.Can anyone help me in this regards.
Thanks in advance.

Data Stored in MongoDB:

```
{

"id":101,

"name": {"firstName":"Mark",

         "lastName":"Antony"

         }
}
```

The Code I am using is:

PersonService.java

```
public List<Audit> searchPerson(Audit audit)
{
List<NameDetails> name=audit.getName();
return mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("name.lastName").is(name.get(0))), Audit.class,COLLECTION_NAME); 
}
```

PersonController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public String search(@ModelAttribute Audit audit, ModelMap model) {  
model.addAttribute("personList", personService.searchPerson(audit)); 
return "output";
}
```

Audit.java

```
@Document
public class Audit {
@Id
private String id;
private List<NameDetails> name;

public String getId() {
    System.out.println("Person: getId");
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    System.out.println("Person: setId");
    this.id = id;
}
public List<NameDetails> getName() {
    System.out.println("Audit: getName");
    return name;
}
public void setName(List<NameDetails> name) {
    System.out.println("Audit: setName");
    this.name = name;
}       

}
```

NameDetails.java

```
package com.register.mongo.model;

public class NameDetails {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
System.out.println("NameDetails: setFirstName");
this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
System.out.println("NameDetails: getLastName");
return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
System.out.println("NameDetails: setLastName");
this.lastName = lastName;
}   
}
```

(output.jsp)UI Page

```
<table border="2">
<c:forEach var="person" items="${personList}">
<tr>
<td>${person.id}</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>${person.lastName}</td> 
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the Audit class?

Comment: @Periklis yeah sure I'll post.

Comment: @Periklis I have included the Audit class in my post

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you should make an extra class and use it in the Audit class

```
public class NameDetails{

private String FirstName;
private String LastName;

public String getFirstName() {
return id;
}

public void seFirstName(String fisrtName) {

    this.FirstName= fisrtName;
}   
public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}
public void setLastName(String LastName) {
    this.LastName = LastName;
}
}
```

and use this class in the Audit.class

```
@Document
public class Audit {
@Id
private String id;
private List name<NameDetails>;
```

and then the setters and getters

Comment: I did what you have posted,I have used List for "name" but it cannot able to fetch the "first Name" it is returning the null value which throws the Null pointer Exception. Do i need to maintain any relationship between name and first name?

Comment: I have edited the post this is my current code as you said i have modified it.. even then it is not taking the value of lastName or firstName.

Comment: I am confused. first of all in this line model.addAttribute("personList", personService.searchPerson(audit)); you expect a list of NameDetails but you return a list of Audit. Also, in the search person function just to test, hardcode a criteria in order to bring everything and then from this result get the getName list back. ie  mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("????, Audit.class,COLLECTION_NAME); in the model.addAttribute("personList", personService.searchPerson(audit).getname);

Comment: I tried Every thing It cannot able to access the firstName and lastName subfields of name. 
I even tried changing the return type to NameDetails but it is returning "NULL".
public List<Audit> searchPerson(NameDetails namedetails){

String name=namedetails.getFirstName();

return mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("name.firstName").is(name)), Audit.class,COLLECTION_NAME);   

}

Comment: Try somethign like this to see if it returns the list public List<Audit> searchPerson(NameDetails namedetails){ String name=namedetails.getFirstName(); return mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(101)), Audit.class,COLLECTION_NAME); } and see if in the list of audit that is returned you can acess firstname and lastname